# Play a sound frequently in React Native App

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

I'm working on a React Native App. I need to play a beep every 500ms. I already have a mp3 file to play and can it play on click. But after clicking the button a few times, it breaks. I used the example code from expo av. I used the [snack](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) from playing audio sounds.
I also could use another mp3 file which is longer, but has to start replaying immediately after ending.

What's the best way to play the beep every 500ms? Using a longer file and replay after ending? Or frequently use the single beep? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you share the necessary code snippets from your app, so we can see what exactly is going on?

Comment: I don't know, what I changed, but its working now... Sorry for the question.....

Comment: Maybe some old cached states in your app which cleaned up after refresh. I'm glad that it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-sound library, have a look at the link below: [link](https://gitter.im/react-native-sound/developers?at=59b67ea0cfeed2eb65f5cccb)

Comment: I already tried the react-native-sound library, but after installing it, the app crashes immediately...

Comment: Could you please share the error?

Comment: I don't know how, but suddenly it worked. Maybe some old cache states or something. It works now. Thank you